# compare the values of a two dimensional array and return a single dimension array in php

Tags: php

how can create a function in php that accept a two dimension array as parameter , something like this:

```
function check_the_length (array[$a_string][$length]){

return $result
}
```

and return an array as an result , like this:

```
$result=(true,false,true,false);
```

By the way if you have any better solution to making such a function please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an assignment question? The use case seems esoteric.  Have you made any attempts at solving it yet? (it isn't difficult)

Comment: give the guy a break. maybe he is new to php. are you not @user363295?

Comment: I started PHP , two weeks ago.

Comment: Michael Berkowsk: Sure i did try, otherwise why should i post it here ?

Comment: @user363295 Yes, please always post your efforts.

Comment: @Cubixsyntax The question reads like an assignment question, which most of us here won't give a complete answer to without evidence of a solid effort.  Just asking for clarification.

Comment: I think @MichaelBerkowski wanted to see effort, as do we all, not just ask a question and get it answered by default.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sure, i do understand that programming is about trying and trying until make it work, i will only post my questions if i'm really stuck in sth, again thanks all

Comment: @ nickhar I did realize that, but yeah that was my fault should have mention my efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do the trick.

```
function check_the_length($array,$given_length){
    $oneDarray = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(strlen($value) == $given_length)){
            $oneDarray[] = true;
        }else{
            $oneDarray[] = false;
        }
    }

    return $oneDarray;
}
```